# How to resolve "ERROR: Unable to load GDAL library" when running r.watershed tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis

I am trying to run [r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.watershed.html) on a dem file and am getting the above error. I have QGIS 3.24.1 installed from OSGeo4W installer on Windows 11. I uninstalled a previous version and deleted corresponding program files, but this has not resolved the problem. Non-Grass tools work fine. I am accessing r.watershed through Grass GIS provider; if I try to open a new mapset through Grass 7 I can go through to 'finish' and receive a 'cannot open new location' message. I don't know if these are related, or something to do with my admin privileges? I am the sole user of the computer.